# Сортировка и выборка верхнего значения

Tags: sql

Есть таблица с названиями городов. Нужно отсортировать города по наименованию и выбрать город с наименьшим и наибольшим количеством символов после сортировки. Остановился на таком запросе:

```
SELECT TOP(1) CITY, LEN(CITY) as first FROM STATION  ORDER BY(first)
```

но к этому запросу не применяется сортировка и не знаю как применить функции MIN и MAX.

Comment: а для чего сортировать, если можно сразу выбрать минимум или максимум количество символов?

Comment: @Denis нужно выбрать одно значение с минимальным колличеством символов

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно использовать подзапрос:

```
select t.city
from station t
where length(t.city) = (select max(length(t1.city)) from station t1)
    or length(t.city) = (select min(length(t1.city)) from station t1)
order by t.city
```

Пример на [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i6BpukvsJzJYGS5nd3WHcP/0).

Comment: А для чего нужно t.city, если можно обратиться сразу к city?

Comment: @Rifter это тот же city, только с элиасом, разницы нет)

Answer (score 0):

Решением моей задачи стал вот такой запрос

```
SELECT TOP 1 CITY, LEN(CITY) FROM STATION WHERE LEN(CITY) = (SELECT MIN(LEN(CITY)) FROM STATION) ORDER BY CITY

SELECT TOP 1 CITY, LEN(CITY) FROM STATION WHERE LEN(CITY) = (SELECT MAX(LEN(CITY)) FROM STATION) ORDER BY CITY
```

Но спасибо @Denis за идею про вложенные запросы.